# GOP size does not correlate with actual latency

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, latency, obs

As far as I know, GOP size should correlate with observable video delay (latency). For example, if GOP size is 2, then delay in video should be near two seconds and so on, at least with CBR. But, when I set GOP size to 2, publish stream to ingest server, consume this stream and measure latency, it is between 0.8-1.2 seconds, not 2+ seconds as excepted. Increasing GOP size leads to same results: with GOP 4 latency is near 2.5 seconds, not 4 seconds.

How I measure this latency: stream working stopwatch from web-camera using OBS to ingest server and calculate difference between stopwatch value and value displayed in stream consumed from ingest. For greater measurement accuracy, I make a photo with stopwatch and actual image from ingest in one field of view.

My OBS settings is [here](https://i.ibb.co/g7StwQm/shutter-28-05-2019-01.png):

[image]

Can you suggest, why do I get such results and how relevant is my statement about correlation between GOP size and video latency? Maybe, H264 settings like "zerolatency" makes some magic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For streaming, each group of pictures is made of `IPPPPPP` --a key frame followed by some number of seconds' worth of P frames. In principle, an encoder need not incur a delay of any given length.  When you send constant bit rate streams, the delay happens because the encoder must sometimes recode some frames at a lower or higher bit rate.

Comment: With GOP=2 encoder must consume raw data from camera for at least 2 seconds to produce `IPPP...` and only then sends this data to upstream (ffmpeg, OBS, etc.), isnt it? And in any case, player must wait at least two seconds to receive first I-frame and display some picture instead "black rectangle". So, I cant understand, where I mistakes in my assumptions. Maybe, GOP=2 is not mean "2 seconds of real time", but something other?

Comment: No, the encoder only need to be delayed by the number of lookahead reference frames. Not a full GOP. And the player delay is determined by the buffer size and protocol.

Comment: So, for example, encoder produce something like `PBPB...` and sent that data to "upstream" immediately, without waiting for I-frame appearance. Dealt with it. But, when player starts consume stream (RTMP; zero buffer size, like `ffplay -fflags nobuffer` or flash player with same setup), it cant start playback until I-frame is received, so player might wait %GOP size% seconds in worst case to receive first I-frame?